Electron React Tailwind Electron-builder

after building my app and i have installed I am getting this error
Uncaught Exception:
/Users/home/Documents/cranesoft-POS/Untitled/dist/mac-arm64/app.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/index.css:1
@tailwind base;
^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1185:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1227:27)
at Object..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1326:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:32)
at node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:12
at Function._load (node:electron/js2c/node_init:2:13357)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1150:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/home/Documents/cranesoft-POS/Untitled/dist/mac-arm64/app.app/Contents/Resources/app/src/index.jsx:3:1

I used electron-builder to build, it an electron react and tailwind project.

Please edit to include the command(s) and config used to build the app, and any relevant to Tailwind usage. IDK if I can help, but that info may make it more clear to someone else.
